# Как сгенерировать звуковой сигнал синусоиду с изменяющейся частотой?

Tags: java, android

Задача научиться генерировать сигналы для вывода на наушник или динамик (под Андроид). 
Синусоида, пила. прямоугольник, но с изменением во времени.

Например синусоида у которой частота меняется от 500Гц до 1000Гц в течении 60 секунд.
Где об этом можно почитать или кто поделится личным опытом работы с этим.

Comment: Покажите что вы пытались сделать? Без этого такой вопрос - оффтопик. Только конкурс спасает его от неизбежного закрытия.

Comment: что вам мешает посмотреть исходники любой программ из маркета с аналогичным функционалом?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Генерируем синусоиду с переменной частотой:

```
private static byte[] generateSineWavefreq(int startFreq, int endFreq, int seconds) {
        int sampleRate=44100; //частота дискретизации - можно взять даже 8000
        double freq, angle;
        byte[] sin = new byte[seconds * sampleRate];
        for (int i = 0; i < sin.length; i++) {
            freq=startFreq+(endFreq-startFreq)*1.0/sin.length*i;
            angle = (2.0 * Math.PI * i)*freq/sampleRate;
            sin[i] = (byte) (Math.sin(angle) * 127);
        }
        return sin;

}
```

Проигрываем полученную волну:

```
 final AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, true);
    try {
        SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(af);
        line.open(af);
        line.start();
        play(line, generateSineWavefreq(5000, 1000, 1));
        line.drain();
        line.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: выделяет красным "sampleRate", SourceDataLine, AudioSystem. Видимо нужны библиотеки дополнительные. А где их взять?

Comment: `import javax.sound.sampled;` творит чудеса, а `sampleRate` надо декларировать.

Comment: .sampled горит красным, где скачать эту библиотеку? Собственно с этого и возник вопрос, когда я нашел примеры, но не смог подключить эту библиотеку.

Comment: @kaaa не пробовали `import javax.sound.sampled.*;`

Comment: Но в API16(например) данная библиотека отсутствует. Так где ее можно взять?

Comment: пробовал конечно, не помогает. Также горит красным  SourceDataLine, AudioSystem. AudioFormat подчеркнут

Comment: Oops... этот пакет недоступен в Android, способ решения [изложен здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803343/javax-cannot-be-imported-in-my-android-app)

Comment: У кого получится решить задачу, напишите пожалуйста здесь.